# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to CAST MULTISET an object via PL/SQL and I'm getting the error mentioned in the subject.

I've checked the datatypes defined in the object itself and the columns in the tables and they appear to match. Same goes for the order I get the values and the order in the object.

But I keep getting the error, here is the full code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TASK_DESTINATION_LIST_OBJTYP AS OBJECT
(
ENTITY_ID NUMBER(9)
,ENTITY_CODE NUMBER(3)
,ENTITY_NAME VARCHAR2(255)
,ENTITY_FAVOTIRE NUMBER(1)
,ENTITY_PATH VARCHAR2(1535) 
,STATE_CODE NUMBER(3)
,STATE_NAME VARCHAR2(50)
,RES_MSG VARCHAR2(2000)
)

/
CREATE TYPE TASK_DESTINATION_LIST_COLTYP AS TABLE OF TASK_DESTINATION_LIST_OBJTYP
```

The Query:

```
SELECT   Decode (tsk_info_t.dest_dev_id,NULL,
                 tsk_info_t.dest_srv_id, 
                 tsk_info_t.dest_dev_id)     AS entity_id,
         Decode (tsk_info_t.dest_dev_id,
                 NULL,1,3) AS entitytyp_code,
         Decode (tsk_info_t.dest_dev_id,NULL,
                 tsk_info_t.dest_srv_name, 
                 tsk_info_t.dest_dev_name) AS entity_name,
         ( 
                SELECT Count(*) 
                FROM   pref_info_t 
                WHERE  Nvl (dev_id, 0) = Nvl (tsk_info_t.dest_dev_id, 0) 
                AND    srv_id = tsk_info_t.dest_srv_id) AS entity_favotire, 
         Decode (tsk_info_t.dest_dev_id,NULL, 
         ( 
                SELECT path 
                FROM   entity_path_view 
                WHERE  dev_id IS NULL 
                AND    srv_id = tsk_info_t.dest_srv_id), 
         ( 
                SELECT path 
                FROM   entity_path_view 
                WHERE  dev_id = dest_dev_id 
                AND    srv_id = dest_srv_id)) AS entity_path, 
         tsk_info_t.state_code                AS state_code, 
         ( 
                SELECT state_type_name 
                FROM   ref_state_type 
                WHERE  state_type_code = state_code ) AS state_name, 
         tsk_info_t.res_msg                           AS res_msg 
FROM     tsk_info_t 
WHERE    tsk_info_t.tsk_id = 5957 
ORDER BY tsk_info_t.dest_srv_name, 
         tsk_info_t.dest_dev_name ASC) 
  AS task_destination_list_coltyp ) 
AS destination_list
```

Comment: That's too much to look through.  Can't you build a minimal script that reproduces the problem and post that instead?  And who knows? Maybe in going through the exercise of isolating the problem to build a smaller script, you might actually figure out the problem.

Comment: There is no way this is your full code Unless your query is actually wrong : where does this `) AS task_destination_list_coltyp ) AS destination_list` came from ?? There is no need of it on the above query unless you didn't pasted full sql code!

Comment: And how does ` tsk_info_t` look like?

Comment: @Trinimon
I apologize, I figured it out, apperantly I cannot user MULTISET when using a UNION as well.